# How to store image in array or other way and retrieve one by one

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting multiple image url in imagedata in this program

' function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

```
   {$("#"+divId).children().attr('src',imageData);}
```

'

also onclick i am getting divID and then showing image based on "img" tag ID.

so my question is that how do we store image url and retrieve one by one for specific "img" tag

```
<a  class="img" id="Image1"><img id="smallImage1" src="" /></a>
        <span class="textarea"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a  class="img" id="Image2"><img id="smallImage2" src="" /></a>
        <span class="textarea"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a  class="img" id="Image3"><img id="smallImage3" src="" /></a>
        <span class="textarea"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a  class="img" id="Image4"><img id="smallImage4" src="" /></a>
        <span class="textarea"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a  class="img" id="Image5"><img id="smallImage5" src="" /></a>
        <span class="textarea"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a  class="img" id="Image6"><img id="smallImage6" src="" /></a>
        <span class="textarea"></span>
    </li>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what is your goal. Can you clarify your question " how do we store image url and retrieve one by one for specific "img" tag ?"

Do you want to store the img url offline in the app ?
Can yo show your code to  get divID and show image based on "img" tag ID  ?

Is this a hybrid worklight app ? If it is and what you want is to store the img url offline, than you can take a look at JSON Store feature documentation here

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html?lang=en

JSON Store is a feature to store data locally in JSON format.